# Writing custom decode path in Amplify GraphQL query request

Tags: flutter, graphql, aws-amplify

I am trying to send a query request in flutter to a graphQL API managed by AWS appsync. Here is the function that does the request.

````
 Future<void> getUsersByLocation(
      String subId, double lat, double long, double distance) async {
    const getUsersByLocation = 'getUsersByLocation';
    final String getUsersDoc = '''
    query getUsersByLocation(\$distance: Float!, \$latitude: Float!, \$longitude: Float!, \$reqUserSubId: String!) {
      $getUsersByLocation(distance: \$distance, latitude: \$latitude, longitude: \$longitude, reqUserSubId: \$reqUserSubId) {
        name
      }
    }
  ''';
    final Map<String, dynamic> inputVars = <String, dynamic>{
      'reqUserSubId': subId,
      'latitude': lat,
      'longitude': long,
      'distance': distance,
    };
    final request = GraphQLRequest<List<User>>(
      document: getUsersDoc,
      modelType: User.classType,
      variables: inputVars,
      decodePath: getUsersByLocation,
    );
    try {
      final response = await Amplify.API.query(request: request).response;
      print('Response: $response.data');
    } catch (error) {
      print('error :${error.toString()}');
    }
  }```
````

The error I get is

```
'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'
```

The graphQL api does return a list of users, but the decode path function is expecting a Map<String, dynamic>?. I need to write a custom decode path function which takes a List, but I am not sure how to do it.

I created a custom function that takes List as input and put the function name as the decodePath, but that did not work. I have also looked through the documentation, but it doesn't mention how to create custom decode path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this issue. Remove the modelType and decodePath and i t will give you the response as a Sting. You can then manually decode the string using json decoder. Here is the fixed code:

````
      String subId, double lat, double long, double distance) async {
    const getUsersByLocation = 'getUsersByLocation';
    final String getUsersDoc = '''
    query getUsersByLocation(\$distance: Float!, \$latitude: Float!, \$longitude: Float!, \$reqUserSubId: String!) {
      $getUsersByLocation(distance: \$distance, latitude: \$latitude, longitude: \$longitude, reqUserSubId: \$reqUserSubId) {
        name
      }
    }
  ''';
    final Map<String, dynamic> inputVars = <String, dynamic>{
      'reqUserSubId': subId,
      'latitude': lat,
      'longitude': long,
      'distance': distance,
    };
    // Remove the modelType and decodePath parameters.
    final request = GraphQLRequest(
      document: getUsersDoc,
      variables: inputVars,
    );
    try {
      final response = await Amplify.API.query(request: request).response;
      if (response.data != null) {
        // Decode the data here
        final jsonData =
            (json.decode(response.data) as Map).cast<String, Object?>();
        print(jsonData);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('error :${error.toString()}');
    }
  }```
````